# What is the difference between these ways to return the time for a datetime column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, time

Right now, I know of 3 ways to return the time:

1. `CONVERT(varchar, Date, 8)`
2. `CONVERT(varchar, Date, 108)`
3. `CONVERT(time, Date)`

What is the difference between #1 and #2, since they return the same answer?

Why does #3 return something that looks different--is it still equivalent to #1/#2's output?

Are there more ways?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to avoid using bare `varchar` - always specify a length (or `max`). Outside of `CONVERT`, the [default length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) is almost never what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [MSDN page for convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  The format `8` is `hh:mi:ss`.  If you add `100` to a format, it uses a four-digit year instead of a two digit year.  Since format `8` is a time format, `8` and `108` have the same output.

The third option converts a `datetime` to a `time`.  A `time` is not a string and has no format.  It's up to the client how it will be displayed, typically using your local computer's Regional and Language Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Points 1. and 2. are equal.
Point 3 returns in other datatype.

Points 1 and 2 are equal but point 3 is different from them.

You can check different formats [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx).